# Записать данные в массив String

Tags: c#, строки, csv

1. Я открыл файл CSV
2. Разделил данные в ячейках `.SetDelimeters(",");`
3. Дальше я хотел записать эти данные в **один массив string**, но у меня не получается это сделать, смог прочитать только одну строку(Row) CSV файла.
4. В файле CSV около 1000 строк, и 13 столбцов. Значение строк каждый раз меняется.

За один прогон с файла читается сразу 13 элементов (столбцов)

```
 while (!tfp.EndOfData)
                {
                    str = tfp.ReadFields();
                }
```

отсюда вытекает -
**Вопрос: как записать все данные из файла CSV в string[] ?**

(не одну строку, а всё содержимое файла CSV)

```
string[] str = {};
            string[] str_result = {};
            using (TextFieldParser tfp = new TextFieldParser(@"C:\Users\Хроматограф\Downloads\Telegram Desktop\История обменов.csv"))
            {
                int i = 0;
                tfp.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
                tfp.SetDelimiters(",");
                while (!tfp.EndOfData)
                {
                    str = tfp.ReadFields();
                }
            }
```

Данные CSV файла имеют формат

```
2019-08-25 12:46:57.79, 1330206, 0.00076094, 487, 0.0000038, 640001, RUB, BTC, QIWI, Fast_BTC_Change, 12AE8f, purchase, confirm_payment.
```

Comment: ну у вас есть какие то свои мысли, а чем проблема? Вы как то сами себе помочь пытались? Что то пробовали?

Comment: 1. Через цикл for пробовал сделать, но ничего не вышло. На вызоде одна строка получается, а мне нужны все строки.
2. Пробовал опираясь на эту статью сделать Как просто работать с / открыть / изменить / сохранить Excel - xlsx / CSV файлы, там получаются коллекции List, их либо добавлять в отдельно через string.Join(" ", List.ToArray), но тогда всё запутанно получается. 

В общем я просто жду советов, я просто не знаю как добавить данные в массив стринг в данной ситуации, получается только одну строку прочитать

Comment: Конечно пытался, всё что знал - я уже использовал, я знаю, что задача примитивная но больше 10 дней уже ничего не могу сделать, кругом только умничают, а толкового сказать не могут

Comment: ну тут 2 момента: 1) вы же понимаете, что CSV файл - это набор строк, где каждая строка - набор значений. Допустим, в файле 3 строки. Что именно в ваш массив должно быть записано? - приведите пример.  2) Вы заранее не знаете сколько строк в файле. То есть вы заранее не можете создать массив нужного размера. А значит вам надо что то, что похоже на массив, но может менять размер - это и есть `List<string>`

Comment: 1. Да конечно я это понимаю, в своём вопросе я даже формат CSV файла привёл: `2019-08-25 12:46:57.79, 1330206, 0.00076094, 487, 0.0000038, 640001, RUB, BTC, QIWI, Fast_BTC_Change, 12AE8f, purchase, confirm_payment.` 
2. Вообще я знаю сколько строк у меня, но иногда количество строк может меняться, поэтому предположим, что я не знаю количество строк. 
@tym32167

Comment: так вы пример для одной строки привели, там все понятно. Но как быть, ксли у вас несколько строк в файле? Что именно должено быть записано в массиве?

Comment: Я просто все эти данные 13 Columns, хочу записать в один массив string 
13 значений(с одной строки) + 13 значений(со следующей строки) + 13 значений(и т.д.). Снизу ответ более менее подходящий, я его под себя попробую настроить, там пишется только два столбца, а мне надо все

Comment: Ну то есть вам надо вместо `string[] str = {};` `var str = new List<string>()`, и вместо ,`str = tfp.ReadFields();`, `str.AddRange( tfp.ReadFields());`

Comment: Возьмите https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/, он нормально парсит csv, включая случаи, когда запятые встречаются в самих значениях

Comment: Распарсить не проблема, проблема это в массив потом записать

Comment: @proritsatel ну так CsvHelper умеет и писать CSV по стандарту. Не изобретайте велосипед.

Comment: Вообще не совсем понятно, что вы ожидаете получить. Массив типа string[]? что должно быть элементами массива? Отдельные значения, без разделения по строкам? Если у вас на входе 100 строк по 13 колонок - вы ожидаете получить один массив, в котором 1300 элементов? Можете привести пример "есть - надо получить" для трех строк?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот функция для решения вашей задачи

```
private string[,] LoadCsv(string filename)
{
    // Читаем файл
    string whole_file = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filename);

    // Разделяем на строки
    whole_file = whole_file.Replace('\n', '\r');
    string[] lines = whole_file.Split(new char[] { '\r' },
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    // Столбцы и строки
    int num_rows = lines.Length;
    int num_cols = lines[0].Split(',').Length;

    // Массив
    string[,] values = new string[num_rows, num_cols];

    // Загрузка
    for (int r = 0; r < num_rows; r++)
    {
        string[] line_r = lines[r].Split(',');
        for (int c = 0; c < num_cols; c++)
        {
            values[r, c] = line_r[c];
        }
    }

    // Возврат
    return values;
}
```

Использование

```
string[,] values = LoadCsv(@"C:\Users\Хроматограф\Downloads\Telegram Desktop\История обменов.csv");
```

Comment: Вы так быстро ответили, Вы сталкивались с похожей ситуацией?
Я ожидал лишь совета, а получил решение, спасибо Вам.
Пришлось только модификатор доступа сменить в функции, и заработало всё отлично.

Comment: Задача стандартная.